# Bad light issue in ODI Cricket

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, technology, interruption

We know that the [bad-light issue in cricket](http://www.espncricinfo.com/pakistan-v-sri-lanka-2013-14/content/story/711729.html) is always happening in test matches to finish that day's game. Since, the traditional cherry or the red leather ball is [harder to pick](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/why-day-and-night-test-matches-were-not-played-yet) under lights.

But, what about white ball matches?

I could see the bad light issue in ODI's too. In the recent match between [South Africa and SriLanka](http://www.espncricinfo.com/sri-lanka-v-south-africa-2014/content/story/757843.html), they were showing the D/L target for every over in the second innings due to bad light problems.

We can also see a match between [Sri Lanka and New ZeaLand](http://www.espncricinfo.com/sri-lanka-v-new-zealand-2013-14/engine/match/668965.html?innings=2;page=1;view=commentary) had ended with D/L method due to the same reason.

Couldn't they switch on more lights? What is the bad light rule for limited overs cricket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Couldn't they switch on more lights? What is the bad light rule for limited overs cricket?

Yes they **CAN**. But only if it is **available** for that *particular* match. Remember, the issue is for **day** matches only.

Umpire's role on bad lights. From [Standard ODI match playing conditions <sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac4ae08b48-04%20Standard%20ODI_2013_19%2009%2013.pdf): (emphasis mine)

> #### 3.7 Use of artificial lights
>
> If in the opinion of the umpires, natural light is deteriorating to an unfit level, they shall authorize the ground authorities to use **the available** artificial lighting so that the match can continue in acceptable conditions. In the event of power failure or lights malfunction, the provisions relating to the delay or interruption of play due to bad weather or light shall apply.

So the umpires can use floodlights in day matches when they think the natural light is deteriorated to an unfit level. But that is possible only if it is available for match. Floodlights are not compulsory for the day matches. And on the match between Sri Lanka and New Zealand the use of floodlights was [not permitted by SLC](http://www.espncricinfo.com/west-indies-v-new-zealand-2014/content/story/757977.html) due to financial savings which hurt their own team. That's why they didn't use floodlights.